# Error authenticating with VS code

Tags: salesforcedx, authentication, sfdx-error

I tried to authenticate my sandbox by authorize an org command and ended up with this error.[image]

Comment: If you have a question with an error message please include it by copy pasting it instead of taking a screen capture. That way others can easily search for it.

Comment: If you do not use VPN the first thing that I would do is reinstall or update your SF CLI

Answer (score 1):

`ECONNRESET` is a Node.js usually happens when there is no response from the server within 2 minutes of wait time.

In your case, it could be there is a network issue or a lost connection. CLI team has added [retry](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1169) for most of the CLI commands, however I do not see one for login.

I suggest if you have VPN getting out of it to see if that makes any difference. It might be also that your local server has connection issues.